# Select all Valid starting letters with Sequelize

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a list of countries which will be separated by starting letter so for example when you click on 'A' it will make an API call to return all the countries beginning with 'A'.

However there are some letters that don't have any countries in our system, and these may change as we update out data.

I want to have a query that will let me know which letters do not have any countries that begin with them, so that I can disable them.

I can do this be running a findOne query for every single letter in the alphabet... but that is not neat or performant. Is there a way to get the data from a single query?

Comment: have you tried regular expressions?, use notRegexp operator
`[Op.notRegexp]: '^[h|a|t]' // NOT REGEXP/!~ '^[h|a|t]' (MySQL/PG only)`

Comment: Are you looking for a sequelize query, or for a pure SQL solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the desired result by using a substring function within a distinct function.

```
 const result = await Countries.findAll({
    attributes: [
      [
        sequelize.fn(
          'DISTINCT',
          sequelize.fn('substring', sequelize.col('countryName'), 1, 1),
        ),
        'letter',
      ],
    ],
    group: [sequelize.fn('substring', sequelize.col('countryName'), 1, 1)],
    raw: true,
  })
```